# How to get second highest Salary of Account Department?

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I having three tables like below -:

```
Create table #temp (id int, DepartmentName varchar(50))
insert into #temp (id,DepartmentName) values(1,'Account')
insert into #temp (id,DepartmentName) values(2,'IT')
select * from #temp

Create Table #temp1(customerid int, CustomerName varchar(50),DepartmentId int)
Insert into #temp1(customerid,CustomerName,DepartmentId)values(1,'Anil',1)
Insert into #temp1(customerid,CustomerName,DepartmentId)values(2,'Ankit',2)
Insert into #temp1(customerid,CustomerName,DepartmentId)values(3,'Mandeep',1)
Insert into #temp1(customerid,CustomerName,DepartmentId)values(4,'Rajesh',2)
Insert into #temp1(customerid,CustomerName,DepartmentId)values(5,'Rohit',1)
Insert into #temp1(customerid,CustomerName,DepartmentId)values(6,'Sharma',0)

Create Table #temp2(customerid int, salary int)
insert into #temp2(customerid,salary)values(1,2000)
insert into #temp2(customerid,salary)values(3,2399)
insert into #temp2(customerid,salary)values(4,4000)
insert into #temp2(customerid,salary)values(2,4500)
insert into #temp2(customerid,salary)values(5,7000)


select max(t2.salary) ,t.CustomerName,t1.DepartmentName
from #temp1 t
left join #temp t1 on t1.id=t.DepartmentId
left join #temp2 t2 on t2.customerid=t.customerid
where DepartmentName='Account' 
and salary<>(select max(tt2.salary)  from #temp2 tt2 
inner join #temp1 tt1 on tt1.customerid=tt2.customerid 
inner join #temp tt on tt.id=tt1.DepartmentId
where tt.DepartmentName='Account') 
group by CustomerName,DepartmentName
```

But not getting second highest salary with this, could please anybody help me with this, i am using max aggregate function in outer query but still getting all the salary of account department.

Comment: we are waiting for upvote!

Comment: i will accept the answer but only if the query above written query will modified, below mentioned answer using Row_Number, Dense_Rank(), through this it can be done easily but i have to do this without using any row number

Comment: @AnilThakur Since You need customer name so using customername in group by will be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Dense_Rank`

```
SELECT
     DepartmentName,
     CustomerName,
     salary
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        t.DepartmentName,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY salary desc) rno,
        salary,
        t1.CustomerName
    FROM #temp t
    JOIN #temp1 t1
        ON t.id = t1.DepartmentId
    JOIN #temp2 t2
        ON t1.customerid = t2.customerid 
    where  t.DepartmentName='Account'
    ) a

WHERE rno = 2
```

**Update**
  Modified Your Query with `dense_rank` since we can not perform group by with customer names.

```
SELECT salary,
       CustomerName,
       DepartmentName
FROM   (SELECT t2.salary,
               t.CustomerName,
               t1.DepartmentName,
               Dense_rank()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY DepartmentName
                   ORDER BY salary DESC) rno
        FROM   #temp1 t
               LEFT JOIN #temp t1
                      ON t1.id = t.DepartmentId
               LEFT JOIN #temp2 t2
                      ON t2.customerid = t.customerid
        WHERE  DepartmentName = 'Account'
               AND salary NOT IN (SELECT Max(tt2.salary)
                                  FROM   #temp2 tt2
                                         INNER JOIN #temp1 tt1
                                                 ON tt1.customerid = tt2.customerid
                                         INNER JOIN #temp tt
                                                 ON tt.id = tt1.DepartmentId
                                  WHERE  tt.DepartmentName = 'Account'))a
WHERE  rno = 1
```

Comment: needs `AND DepartmentName='Account'` to complete the answer :)

Comment: @EdwardComeau I have given solution for all departments. I will update it.

Comment: Of course, and best to attack it that way first. Already received my +1.

Comment: its working, but can't be do it the way i have write the code in the question above, i need to do this using group by and the way i have write the code, let me know what's wrong in the query i have written, why max is not working and where clause?

Comment: @AnilThakur Your sub query has problem max(tt2.salary) will gives only first highest. So your query returning other than highest salary. it means second, third etc. And also your Group by last one with customername.

Comment: @AnilThakur I always suggest to use Rank() or Dense_Rank() or Row_number() Functions to find 2nd highest or 3rd highest values etc.

Comment: So you saying there is no other way then using Rank() or Dense_Rank()?

Comment: I am not saying no other way. My suggestion is using Rank related functions will be the best fit for your question.\

Comment: but sir i have to do this without using Row_number(), Rank() or Dense_Rank(), that's what i tried to this in my query

Comment: Any specific requirement for you to do with out of Rank() functions??

Comment: @AnilThakur Revome customer name  both in select and group by clause and try in your query since you want only second highest salary for a department. you will get it. Burt you will not get customer name. If you want customer name also then go for Rank() no other way.

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
 SELECT #temp1.customerid,
       CustomerName,
       DepartmentName,
       Max(salary)
FROM   #temp
       JOIN #temp1
         ON id = DepartmentId
       JOIN #temp2
         ON #temp1.customerid = #temp2.customerid
WHERE  id = 1
       AND salary NOT IN (SELECT Max(salary)
                          FROM   #temp2)
GROUP  BY #temp1.customerid,
          CustomerName,
          DepartmentName
```

Comment: I think you need to give solution for all departments second highest salary. Not for single.

Comment: Then your max(Salary) FROM   #temp2 is wrong that will not gives each department highest salary.

Comment: This works because the Account department is filtered by the `WHERE id = 1` clause, but it isn't a very elegant way to achieve the result.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest and fastest way of doing it. Better than using rank...

```
select top 1
    t1.Customerid,
    t1.CustomerName,
    t2.Salary,
    t.DepartmentName

from #temp1 t1

Join #temp2 t2
    on t2.customerId = t1.Customerid

Join #temp t
    on t.id = t1.departmentid
    and t.departmentName = 'account'

where t2.salary <
    (
    select MAX(t2.salary)
    from #temp1 t1
    Join #temp2 t2
        on t2.customerId = t1.Customerid
    Join #temp t
        on t.id = t1.departmentid
        and t.departmentName = 'account'
    )

order by t2.salary desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte AS(

SELECT t1.customerid,t1.CustomerName,t2.DepartmentName FROM #temp1 t1 
                                        LEFT JOIN #temp t2 ON t1.DepartmentId = t2.id)

,cte2 as(
SELECT t3.*,t4.salary,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t4.salary DESC) AS rno FROM cte t3
                                        LEFT JOIN #temp2 t4 ON t3.customerid = t4.customerid)
SELECT * FROM cte2 WHERE rno=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I also try  :)

```
with cte as 
(
    select
        c.CustomerName,
        d.DepartmentName,
        s.Salary,
        RowNumber = row_number() over (partition by c.DepartmentId order by s.Salary)
    from 
        #temp1 c
        inner join #temp d on d.Id = c.DepartmentId
        inner join #temp2 s on s.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
)
select
    CustomerName,
    DepartmentName,
    Salary
from
    cte
where
    RowNumber = 2
    and
    DepartmentName='Account';
```

**Edited**: `dance_rank` is better here. Buddi gave [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40395579/623190) earlier!

Comment: using row number will give you the second row ordered by salary, when your top two customers have a salary of 7,000 each then you'll have a result of 7,000. You might not want that outcome, perhaps you still want 4,500 even though this is now the third record.

Comment: Yes! Edward you are right! dense_rank is better here.

Answer (score -2):

```
select t1.customerid,t2.salary,t1.CustomerName,t.DepartmentName 
from #temp2 t2 
 join  #temp1  t1
on t2.customerid=t1.customerid
 join #temp t
on t1.DepartmentId =t.id
where salary=(
select MIN(salary) as salary from (select distinct top(2) salary from #temp2 order by salary desc )T)
```

Try above code

Comment: Fails to answer the question correctly and very poor formatting.